# How To Init A UIView That Exists In Interface Builder But Also Requires Init In Code

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller, swift

Here is my view class

```
class V_TakePhoto:UIView{

    var _takePhotoCallback:(iImage)->Void?

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        _takePhotoCallback = nil
    }


    @IBAction func takePhoto(sender: AnyObject) {

        println("Here we go!")
    }


    func initWithCameraCallback((iImage)->Void)
    {

    }

}
```

This class is a UIView subclass. In the interface builder I selected the ViewController class, and then selected its View object. I assigned V_TakePhoto to this view object.

In the ViewController class, which I assigned to C_TakePhoto class, I want to init the V_TakePhoto class.

As you can see, I want it to have a callback variable that it gets passed at run time. However, because the view is already getting initialized from the interface builder, init(coder) is getting called first.

As it stands right now it seems hacky that I need to have 2 init functions. One where interface builder calls it, then again when my ViewController inits the view with its callback. Also I will have a number of variables, and I need to pre-init them in the init(coder) call then RE-init them again when the ViewController calls the 'true' init on the V_PhotoClass. Seems very hacky to me, there must be a clean 'correct' way to do this.

Can you suggest a cleaner way to handle a situation where you have variables and need to init a view despite there being an init(coder) call from the interface builder?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a function in     `V_TakePhoto` and call it in both     `V_TakePhoto`'s     `init(coder)` and ViewController's     `viewDidLoad()`, something like :

In     `V_TakePhoto` :

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    specialInit()
}

func specialInit() {
    // some of your view initialization
}
```

In your View Controller :

```
@IBOutlet weak var takePhotoView: V_TakePhoto!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // this method is called after the view controller has loaded its view hierarchy into memory.
    takePhotoView.specialInit() // RE-init
}
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid something like this, also the complier complains if init variables in, say specialInit. Swift, as of right now, demands vars be init in the actual init method (you cant use helper methods for the first init)

Comment: Sorry, didn't know what you were hoping to avoid. Non-optional vars cannot be assigned to `nil`, you must initialize them in `init()` or at the time of their declaration. So what you should do is define `_takePhotoCallback` as an implicitly unwrapped optional (exclamation mark) that you will initialize elsewhere. Does it help?